# How to mask PII data with leverage of logstach-logback-endcoder and format data?

Tags: java, json, logback

my project prints normal log, I need to refactor it into json format and mask PII data.
I checked [logstash-logback-encoder](https://github.com/logfellow/logstash-logback-encoder), seems it's perfect. I trid but cannot achieve my goals.

my logback configuration:

```xml
<configuration debug="true">
    <appender name="stdout" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder class="net.logstash.logback.encoder.LoggingEventCompositeJsonEncoder">
            <jsonGeneratorDecorator class="net.logstash.logback.mask.MaskingJsonGeneratorDecorator">
                <defaultMask>****</defaultMask>
                <path>password</path>
            </jsonGeneratorDecorator>
            <providers>
                <timestamp>
                    <timeZone>UTC</timeZone>
                </timestamp>
                <pattern>
                    <pattern>
                        {
                        "time":"%d{yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS+08:00}",
                        "level": "%level",
                        "message": "%m"
                        }
                    </pattern>
                </pattern>
            </providers>
        </encoder>
    </appender>
    <root level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="stdout"/>
    </root>
</configuration>
```

my application:

```java
log.info("I want to print {}", new User("Jax","secret"));
```

here `User` is a POJO, only have 2 string fileds.

what I got in console:

```json
{"@timestamp":"2023-11-28T15:46:24.5832727Z","level":"INFO","message":"I want to print User(userName=Jax, password=secret)"}
```

my expection:

```json
{"@timestamp":"2023-11-28T15:46:24.5832727Z","level":"INFO","message":"I want to print {\"userName":\"Jax\",\"password\":\"***\"}"}
```

my analysis:

the decorator `MaskingJsonGeneratorDecorator` does work, but form `JsonGenerator` viewpoint, it takes the whole output as it's target instead of my own parameter (POJO instance). if I change the `<path>password</path>` to `<path>message</path>` it can mask the whole message. but I need it only focus on the POJO instance, I tried:

1. change the pattern, asked it to parse the message into json object by `#tryJson{...}`
2. change `path` accordingly
3. use jackson serialize `User` before printing

it does work. but since my original log statement isn't json, it could be a xmlstring, json string or POJO.

I also tried to use `MaskingJsonGenerator` to implement my own `jsonserializer`, it can't work because of StackOverflowException.

what I supposed to change my logback configuration and log related class? please help. thanks a lot.